# Excluding a node from reads in mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'm looking for a customized configuration for mongodb replicaset.

I have N production nodes where i should perform reads.
I have a single node where there is an import process that produces a lot of reads and a few writes.

What I'd like is to have the import process reading and writing only on the local node and the N production nodes to avoid querying that single node

Any suggestion about this ?

Thanks

Comment: in a replica set there can only be one primary.  so writes can only go to the replica node that happens to be primary at the time.  can you clarify exactly what you mean by "reading and writing only on the local node"?

Comment: Hi Asya, i just missed the point of having a single primary.. yep, that is the solution. Using a priority=0 secondary nodes for production. Anyway, by local node i mean the same psychical machine where the process and mongodb are running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that writes always go to the replica set primary. You can separate read traffic, but any writes must go to the primary.

You could mark the node as hidden as @efan suggested. In that case, any app that connects using replica set semantics will not use the node. To make the import process read from the hidden node, you will have to connect directly to that node. But that client can't write, because it's not connected to the primary. So you'd have to create a second client object that connected to the replica set, and use one for reading and the other for writing.

I think a better solution is to use tagged read preferences. Give the import node a tag like "function":"import", and the other nodes a tag like "function":"normal". Then have your production nodes specify a tagged read preference of "function":"normal", and your import job specify a tagged read preference of "function":"import". This will separate read traffic.

Note that tagged read preference ia a fairly recent feature, so you might have to upgrade your client driver, or your mongodb server, or both, if they are old.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-tag-sets

Answer (score 0):

This [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/) suggests using [hidden](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members) and [delayed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/#replica-set-delayed-members) secondaries for dedicated functions.